# sqlserver express connection error cannot connect to readonly database windows starter edition

Tags: .net, connection, runtime-error, sql-server-express

Hi I am developing an application using visual studio 2010 framework 4 C# desktop application,sqlserver express 2008 edition for some reason i cannot install sqlserver management studio i have to use express database by giveing full mdf file path . I have added connection string in app.config My application in windows starter edition, gives following error

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Failed to update database "C:\PROGRAM FILES\DIGIPLY\CMS\DB\DatabaseName.MDF" because the database is read-only.
```

is working fine in developer computer, I have tried it in windows xp and windows 7 but  in windows 7 starter edition it gives

```
<add key="dbconnection" value="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DB\DatabaseName.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=False"/>
```

Comment: what version of windows is running on the development workstation? And the only thing that you are doing is copying the .mdf file to the new system?

Comment: SQL server express is installed as a service (normally the network service) check that the network service has full access to the file and that the file properties do not have the read only bit set

Comment: windows 7 ultimate  at developer and problem at windows 7 starter edition

Comment: @Mike.Beeler i added deployment project and added the mdf file in that project and network service has all the rights

Comment: so sql server express has installed without error on the windows starter version? I would attempt to duplicate on another system another copy of windows 7 ultimate to verify that the install works and you are not running into a limitation of windows starter version

Comment: I notice that you have your database file in a subdirectory of program files just as a test could you move the .mdf file to your my documents folder and change your connection string and retry? Normal programs do not have access to program files ... unless running as admin.

Comment: my application is working in windows 7 ultimate  and windows xp with same settings  but not in windows starter edition